# Getting cookies on contextMenu tab instead of active window

Tags: google-chrome-extension

So I explain my issue and lets see if someone knows what I'm doing wrong.

I am creating a chrome extension that adds an option in the context menu. As part of the action I need to fetch one cookie and with the value of the cookie, open a new tab.

My problem is seems to be with the Mac version (I cannot reproduce it on Windows, but I haven't tried other linux distros) that if the user has a normal window and an incognito window opened, if he has the focus on the incognito window, and does the right-click on the normal window to trigger the contextMenu action (MacOS doesn't change the focus), chrome tries to get the cookie from the incognito window and open the new tab in the incognito window, which is the one focused, instead of the window that received the right-click.

Any Idea on how to fix it?

(In order to reproduce, you need to `Allow in incognito`)

script.js

```js
function openTab(info, tab) {
  console.log(tab.url); // returns the clicked url, not the incognito
  chrome.cookies.getAll({}, function(cookies){
    console.log(cookies); // shows only the cookies of the incognito
    // this will open the tab in the incognito window
    chrome.tabs.create({
      url: "https://www.example.com"
    });
  });  
}

chrome.contextMenus.create({
  "title":"Open tab",
  "contexts":["link"],
  "onclick":openTab
});
```

With the following manifest

```js
{
  "name": "Getting cookies context change",
  "description": "Example of what goes wrong while getting cookie",
  "version": "0.1",
  "permissions": [
    "contextMenus",
    "cookies",
    "activeTab",
    "<all_urls>"
  ],
  "background": {
    "scripts": ["script.js"]
  },
  "manifest_version": 2
}
```

Comment: `tab.url` in handleClick + at least "activeTab" in manifest's "permissions"

Comment: Please [edit] the question to be on-topic: include a [mcve] that *duplicates the problem*. For Chrome extensions or Firefox WebExtensions you almost always need to include your *manifest.json* and some of the background, content, and/or popup scripts/HTML, and often webpage HTML/scripts. Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't my code working the way I want?") must include: (1) the desired behavior, (2) a specific problem or error and (3) the shortest code necessary to reproduce it *in the question itself*. Please also see: [What topics can I ask about here?](/help/on-topic), and [ask].

Comment: Example minified, and added some debug result on `tab.url`. 
Thanks for helping me get a better question ;) any Idea whats wrong?

Comment: See the [documentation](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/cookies#method-getAll) and specify `storeId` obtained via getAllCookieStores.

Comment: And which one do I pick of the array returned? because the problem is that it not only gets the cookies from the incognito window, but it also opens the new tab in the incognito window. (as you see, I do nothing with the cookie, is just to change the context :S